# OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionExit2D being called simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a moving platform which gets activated only when player jumps onto it. Below is the piece of code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{        
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {            
        moving = true;
        collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    }        
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{        
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Exiting");
        //collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

But as soon as the player lands on the platform, both the OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionExit2D are being called because of which the code is not working as expected. Why is this happening?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the `OnCollisionEnter2D` by `OnCollisionStay2D` and it worked like a charm. Although I still don't understand that why `OnCollisionExit2D` is being called.